# How to get a value in td from the loop

Tags: jquery

```html
<table data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-key-events="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-resizable="true" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="saveId" data-show-export="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Birthday</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <?php foreach($people as $person) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $person["name"]; ?></td>
        <td id="birthday"><?=$person["birthday"] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $person["address"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

From this table, I would like to get a birthday value from the loop.

How can I get each value in jQuery?

Comment: So this is not a PHP question. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and post PURE RENDERED HTML, script and CSS in a [mcve]

Comment: Also ID must be UNIQUE. Make it a class `$(".birthday").each(function() { console.log($(this).text())});`

Comment: Ok, now it is a snippet. Please unroll the loop with test data. In any case, my comment is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ID must be UNIQUE. Make it a class

```js
$(".birthday").each(function() { // or more specific: $("tbody tr td.birthday")
  console.log($(this).text())
});

// or

$(".birthday").each(function() {
  const bDay = $(this).text() 
  const name = $(this).prev().text();
  console.log(name,bDay)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-show-columns="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true" data-show-refresh="true" data-key-events="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-resizable="true" data-cookie="true" data-cookie-id-table="saveId"
  data-show-export="true" data-click-to-select="true" data-toolbar="#toolbar">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Birthday</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Fred</td>
      <td class="birthday">25 May 1990</td>
      <td>Road 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Joe</td>
      <td class="birthday">5 June 1980</td>
      <td>Road 1</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```